# Magento both AND and OR conditions in a collection

Tags: magento, collections, filter, multiple-conditions

I want make a query which looks like below to filter some products (using attributes) from product collection.

```
SELECT <attributes>
FROM <tables & joins>
WHERE (<some AND conditions>) OR (<some AND conditions>)
```

`WHERE` condition should filter products that match either first set of `AND` conditions or second set of `AND` conditions.
Problem is I can't find a way to add an `OR` condition in between multiple `AND` conditions.
Can anyone help me to code above where condition using Magento `addAttributeToFilter()`? or any other functions?

Answer (score 1):

If i'm understanding you correctly I think you need to do some variation of this:

```
->addAttributeToFilter(...filter here...)
->addAttributeToFilter(array(
    array(
        'attribute' => 'special_to_date',
        'date' => true,
        'from' => $dateTomorrow
    ),
    array(
        'attribute' => 'special_to_date',
        'null' => 1
    )
));
```

which would be:

`...filter here... AND (special_to_date >= '2012-07-03' OR special_to_date IS NULL)...`